# Convert timestamp column in a csv

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a tab separated csv. The rows look like following:

```
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49+02  2
```

How do i remove the **+02** (i assume it can be any number, not only +02) bit from the *timestamp* column for all the rows?

P.S. What if I there where two timestamps in one row? Like

```
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
```

?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the UTC offset? It seems a pretty important part of the timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that is an UTC offset. However in the current logic they just get rid of it, so i though that i would just go with the flow.

Comment: wrt `What if I there where two timestamps in one row?` - then you would write code to handle them however you want them handled. If you'd like help with that then at a minimum provide the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2):

Give this one-liner a try, I didn't test, but should work

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{sub(/[+][0-9]+$/,"",$(NF-1))}7' file
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. Works great for me.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this small update, didn't take into account all cases from the start -_-

Comment: @Dennis It is different if `+02` can be at the end of **certain** column(s) or **any** column(s). What is the requirement? remove any `+02` suffixes from all columns? Or remove only in x and y columns?

Comment: It is the 2nd. The +2 can only be in the end of specific columns.

Comment: @Dennis then just do `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t";re="[+][0-9]+$"}{sub(re,"",$(NF-1));sub(re,"",$(NF-2))}7' file` It should apply the removal on last two columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's|+[0-9]\+\([[:space:]]\+[0-9]\+\)$|\1|' file
```

Here I used regexp to replace `+02  2` at the end of the line to just `2`

Important: it would work with any numbers after plus sign, but it's important to have this plus sign, without it it wouldn't work.

Updated:

> P.S. What if I there where two timestamps in one row? Like

In this case it wouldn't work and you could use another approach, that is based on replacing date with timestamps by dates without it:

```
sed -i 's|\([0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\)+[0-9]\+|\1|g' file
```

But dates should be in the format like `07:56:59+02`.

Comment: I though of getting rid of it completely :)

Comment: Yes and this will remove it, but we need to hold the last column, right?

Comment: And what if we there were 2 and more timestamps in one row?

Comment: Whoop whoop! Thank you!

Comment: @Dennis You're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since `+` followed by a number doesn't occur in any other field (column) we don't have to worry about which field we affect:

```
$ cat file
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49+02  2
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
$
$ sed 's/+[0-9]*//' file
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49  2
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
$
$ sed 's/+[0-9]*//g' file
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49  2
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
$
$ awk '{sub(/+[0-9]*/,"")}1' file
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49  2
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2016-04-25 07:56:59+02  2
$
$ awk '{gsub(/+[0-9]*/,"")}1' file
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
57767500    some@email.com  3784    text_value  2016-04-25 07:30:49  2
57760234    some@email.com  3791    text_value  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2016-04-25 07:56:59  2
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to include some more truly representative sample input and expected output.